# how to retain the tab content after postback occured by other tab

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am showing six google charts in `tab1` and a listbox and couple of gridviews in tab2. When the page is rendered the first time there is no problem, but when a postback happens on `selectionindexchanged` of listbox `tab2`, all chart content gets lost and shows the exception `Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference` in Tab1. How can I overcome this situation?

```
<div id="contentArea">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab-1">Incidents Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-2">Pending Incidents Summary</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tab-3">SLA Analysis</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab-1">
        <table id="table_Incident_Summary" style="width:100%;" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td>Incidents Logged - Last 6 months</td>
                <td>Incidents Logged - CategoryWise</td>
                <td>Incidents Logged - Severitywise</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="chart1" height="200" width="400"></td>
                <td id="chart2" height="200" width="400"></td>
                <td id="chart3" height="200" width="400"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Incidents Reopened - Last 6 months</td>
                <td>SLA - Last 6 months</td>
                <td>Average closing time - Last 6 months</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="chart4" height="200" width="400"></td>
                <td id="chart5" height="200" width="400"></td>
                <td id="chart6" height="200" width="400"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div ID="tab-2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Update-panels for those controls that you want to change on Post-back and make 'click' events as their triggers. Don't forget to set Update-panels' update mode as 'Conditional'.

If you want to refresh Gridview1 on Button1 click, then put Gridview1 in an update-panel and use Button1.Click() event as the trigger.

You can also put your charts in Update-panel and make them conditional so they don't get refreshed.